# See HTML response in chrome network

Tags: html

Hello when I send my html page with google chrome I can't see the path in the link Bar Though I use the method get and when I open the network angle I can't find the query request either [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnx0e.png)

Comment: can you share the content from the network tab please?

Comment: https://codepen.io/fethi87/pen/yLPGBWp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first view is see that your request goes again a html page. Then you will get as response the html. But i suggest you will send some data. Then you have to add in every form element a name selector. Like `<input name="username" ...>`.

Then you need a endpoint which can handle your request. A HTML side cant do that. You need a serverside endpoint. Like api.php etc.

Comment: I'm just a beginner in html but I saw in the course that I'm learning from it that it can show the username and the email in the link bar after he send them, and it  didn't use any thing except a html code.

Comment: Without the `name` attribute, your fields won't be included in the query string.

Comment: @أبومحمد If you will add for example name="username" then you will see in the developer tool the query string `https://cdpn.io/cpe/boomboom/gggg.html?username=hello` and below you will find the key value pairs. in this case would be `username: hello`